# ethereumj & etherscan, discrepancies between blocks described- during sync

Tags: synchronization, ethereumj, ropsten-revival

I've cloned the [ethereumj codebase](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj), and in the directory `ethereumj/` run it for *testnet* with the following command:

```
./gradlew runRopsten
```

However, during the block synchronization process there is a discrepency between the blocks as they're described in the console, and the corresponding block number as described by etherscan.

For instance, consider `Block #588712`, pictured below:

[image]

The console asserts that it contains `70` transactions, however- on etherscan it describes that block as containing `0` transactions. See below:

[image]

---

---

---

---

---

Here is an additional example:

---

---

[image]

[image]

---

---

---

---

---

One can also run this client with the command

```
./gradlew run -PmainClass=org.ethereum.samples.RopstenSample
```

It results in the same error, as demonstrated here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the ethereumj client is somehow trying to access the "*original ropsten*" testnet whereas etherscan is displaying information from the `ropsten-revival` testnet, as it says here:

[image]

If that's the case, how can I get the ethereumj client to connect to the `ropsten-revival` testnet?

But if something else is going on- what is it?